# Launching several instances of lprun simultaneously results in a crash

Tags: linqpad

When I run several instances of lprun at the same time, I get errors similar to:

```
c:\gits\twillLaunch\TextServiceV1>c:\bin_drop\lprun.exe tola.linq
error CS0042: Unexpected error creating debug information file 'c:\Users
\igord\AppData\Local\Temp\LINQPad\_myicbruv\query_cqlttm.PDB' -- 
'c:\Users\igord\AppData\Local\Temp\LINQPad\_myicbruv\query_cqlttm.pdb: 
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Is this a supported scenario?